# Disagreements with button proximity

Tags: buttons, placement

On the Sign In page, we have two links. One is for Clients, which is the primary login form. There is a button for our Employee Login, which is a Single Sign On process.

I put the button on the top right initially to separate those experiences.

Product Management wants me to put it on the bottom of the login page, because they think it will confuse the users at the top right. However, referencing the Gestalt Principle - I believe by placing the Employee Login Button in closer proximity to the login form will actually create more confusion.

Ideally I would like to A/B test this, but currently, we haven't recruited any users willing to participate in the user testing. (I'm a one-man show, so it's incredibly overwhelming. Any suggestions on how to user test online would be very appreciated!)

Based on your experience and knowledge, which option makes more sense? (Pictures included below.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the 'Employee Login' button function like the 'Sign In' button (i.e. I complete the un/pw fields and then click it) or does it invoke another page/form with another set of inputs?

Comment: No. It uses the Microsoft Outlook Single Sign On process - all our employees use Microsoft Outlook accounts, where as the clients have a username / password.

Comment: So what happens if I come to this screen and just click 'Employee Login'?

Comment: It takes you to the Applicant Insight OAUTH - where it will ask you for username / password on the first time (with Microsoft outlook) - and then you just select your account. Kind of similar to "Login with Google"

Comment: Is there a scenario where an employee is a client or vice versa? I assume it's not case. So if I am a client, I do not need employee login and if I am an employee I do not need client login. right? Or am I missing some detail here? Can it not be handled at User Management, and allow me to see what is absolutely necessary for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you have made enough of a difference between the visual design of the two different sign in interface elements to make a distinction, although I do think that having it on the top right means that only people who know to look for it there will find it, whereas putting it in the main section of the form won't have that effect.

I have never known assertions and assumptions to be particularly convincing for management, and the same can be said for design principles because context is also important in design decisions.

Therefore, I think perhaps testing is the most impartial way to break the deadlock, but you are right in making a design decision based on a principle rather than assumption.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very sorry but I find both designs very confusing.

If I'm a client, what do I do? I'd know my name/paswd combination so I just enter those and then click 'Sign In', right? I can see that there's also a link if I'm having trouble signing in and then there's a link which presumably explains WHY I should want to 'create an account' -- although you may wish to re-phrase this as 'Make a new Sign In account' since this is what you actually call the process everywhere else. This is ALL a client needs to see on the front page.

If I'm an employee, after my first day I know all I have to do is hit the 'Employee Login' button which does me a quick login on the basis of stored credentials. So what I want to do there is hit it quick and get logged in.

It's ugly to have them both on the same page really. Ideally, I'd create a separate page for the 'employee login' dialogue - there may also be issues with employee logins that you might have to handle which a client shouldn't see and so you'll have the real estate for that with this solution.

Yes, I know. Sometimes it all just HAS to be on the same page. So you need loads more visual separation. One solution is to envisage the page as quartered. Top Left quarter: client signin, complete with logo and other enticing images. Bottom Right quarter: employee login area, obviously quite plain, different visual style.

Ensure that whatever screen your employees use, the employee login does NOT go 'below the fold' so you may have to indulge in some '@media only screen and ...' styling. Having client login at top left means it shouldn't ever vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a simple link instead of a button and separate from the rest of the form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can fix this.

1) ask login credentials for client and employee in different tabs...

2) you can just have one login form and direct the user to right experience basis the type of login - Client or Employee... 
So if user logins using clients credential, show him the client dashboard... or if the user is an employee, show him the employee dashboard.